# linear relaxation of an optimization problem

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, global-optimization, combinatorial-optimization

I'm reading an article lately, and there is one point which confuses me. 
So, we have the following constrained binary quadratic problem.

min $x^{T}Qx$

with the constraints that $Ax\leq b$ and $x\in \{0,1\}^{n}$.

This can be relaxed into the following:

min $\sum_{1\leq i<j \leq n}2q_{ij}y_{ij}+\sum_{i=1}^{n}q_{ii}x_i$

with the constraints that

$Ax\leq b$,

$y_{ij}\geq x_i +x_j-1  \text{for any } i,j \text{ with } i<j \text{ and } q_{ij}>0$

$y_{ij}\leq x_i \text{ for any } i,j \text{ with } i<j \text{ and } q_{ij}<0$

$y_{ij}\leq x_j \text{ for any } i,j \text{ with } i<j \text{ and } q_{ij}<0$

$0\leq x_i \leq 1 \text{ for any } i=1,2,...n$

$y\geq 0$

So, the solution of the relaxed optimization problem would serve as a lower bound of the optimal solution for the original optimization problem. 
Could anyone help me explain the relaxation part? I was thinking to prove

$\sum_{1\leq i <j \leq n}2q_{ij}y_{ij} + \sum_{i=1}^{n} q_{ii}x_i \leq \sum_{j=1}^n(\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_iq_{ij}x_j)$.

It seems that the term $\sum_{i=1}^{n}q_{ii}x_i$ of the left part would cancel out the term $\sum_{j=1}^{n}x_i^{2}q_{ij}$ of the right part. Then, what shall I do next? Any comments would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can most easily prove this by working with an intermediate problem where $y_{i,j}=x_{i}x_{j}$ is a constraint.  Then relax the integraility to bounds of 0 and 1 and show that the constraints relating $x$ and $y$ are a relaxation of $y_{i,j}=x_{i}x_{j}$.